# Get distinct rows from RDD[type] in scala Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Let say I have an RDD of format like this RDD[employee] and sample data as follows :-

```
FName,LName,Department,Salary
dubert,tomasz ,paramedic i/c,91080.00,
edwards,tim p,lieutenant,114846.00,
edwards,tim p,lieutenant,234846.00,
edwards,tim p,lieutenant,354846.00,
elkins,eric j,police,104628.00,
estrada,luis f,police officer,96060.00,
ewing,marie a,clerk,53076.00,
ewing,marie a,clerk,13076.00,
ewing,marie a,clerk,63076.00,
finn,sean p,firefighter,87006.00,
fitch,jordan m,law clerk,14.51
fitch,jordan m,law clerk,14.51
```

Expected Output :-

```
dubert,tomasz ,paramedic i/c,91080.00,
edwards,tim p,lieutenant,354846.00,
elkins,eric j,police,104628.00,
estrada,luis f,police officer,96060.00,
ewing,marie a,clerk,63076.00,
finn,sean p,firefighter,87006.00,
fitch,jordan m,law clerk,14.51
```

I want a single row of each based on distinct Fname

Answer (score 1):

I think you want do something like that:

```
df
.groupBy('Fname)
.agg(
  first('LName),
  first('Department),
  first('Salary)
)
```

Comment: Hey, don't you think, groupBy is very heavy operation , grouping a batch means iterating over all the rows which is log(n) operation. this grouping will itself take 1-2 second.

Comment: @Pinnacle group by is a widely user operation and in your case is an expected solution.

Comment: Yeah @AlexandrosBiratsis I understand but I just wanted to know if there is any other way that is possible without using group by as in my case it was creating overhead and processing time. May be that's the only way. Well thanks for the response.